# Configuration of $n$ points inside rectangle

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

Given a finite set $S$ of at least $2$ points in the Euclidean plane and $x\in S$ write
$$
d_S(x)=\min_{y\in S,\, y\neq x}d(x,y)
$$
and
$$
d(S)=\sum_{x\in S}d_S(x)
$$
Now given a rectangle (product of closed bounded intervals) $R$ in the plane and $n\geq2$: Which $S\subset R$ with $|S|=n$ maximizes $d(S)$?

Comment: You are packing circles into the rectangle.  Packing problems are hard, even with all the circles the same size.  See packomania.com for examples to see how few solutions are known to be optimal and the range of chaos in the solutions.

Comment: How is this exactly linked to circle packings? Note that the points may lie on the boundary of the rectangle.

Comment: Each point excludes any other points from the circle centered on the point and radius the distance in your formula.  You allow the circles to overlap, but you should be able to transform it to a problem with a circle around each point.  This is easy if all the circles are the same size, but harder if you allow different sizes.  I think allowing different sizes just makes the problem harder as there are more configurations to try.

Comment: You can solve this precisely for small $n$, and for very large $n$ a hexagonal packing is most often close to the best.